# Error Failed to load PDF document using ASP.NET Core MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written code to export database table data into a PDF. The code is working, but when a PDF file is downloaded, I get an error

> Error - failed to load PDF document

I'm attaching the code please go through it if you know any solution please let me know.

Private method `getexportdata`:

```
private void getexportdata()
{
            try
            {
                string sql = null;

                if (role == "BLC")
                {
                    sql = "select SurveyInformationId,AreaName,userinfo.EmployeeName,BranchName,SurveyDate,ManagerApprove,u.EmployeeName as manager from SurveyInformation inner join Branch on Branch.BranchId = SurveyInformation.BranchId inner join UserInfo on UserInfo.UserId = SurveyInformation.CreatedBy inner join UserInfo u on u.UserId = SurveyInformation.ManagerApproveid where ManagerApprove = 'Approve' or CSRApprove = 'Pending'";
                }

                if (role == "Admin")
                {
                    sql = "select SurveyInformationId,AreaName,userinfo.EmployeeName,BranchName,SurveyDate,ManagerApprove,u.EmployeeName as manager from SurveyInformation inner join Branch on Branch.BranchId = SurveyInformation.BranchId inner join UserInfo on UserInfo.UserId = SurveyInformation.CreatedBy inner join UserInfo u on u.UserId = SurveyInformation.ManagerApproveid where ManagerApprove = 'Approve' or CSRApprove = 'Pending'";
                }

                database db = new database(); db.openconnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, db.cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchId", Session["BranchId"].ToString());
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session["UserId"].ToString());

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                db.closeconnection();

                ExportToPDF(dt, "SurveyInformation Report");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
}
```

Private method `ExportToPDF`:

```
private void ExportToPDF(DataTable dt, string s)
{
            try
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string filename = s + DateTime.Now.ToString(" dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss") + ".pdf";
                    System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

                    DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                    dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    dgGrid.DataBind();

                    //Get the HTML for the control.
                    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                    //Write the HTML back to the browser.
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                    //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename + ".pdf");
                    this.EnableViewState = false;
                    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                    Response.End();
                    Response.Close();
                    Response.Flush();

                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Report Export Succesfully')", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No Data to Export')", true);
                }
            }
            catch { }
}
```

Protected method `btexportblc_Click`:

```
protected void btexportblc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getexportdata();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use Itextsharp to generate the PDF file.

More detials, you could refer to below codes:

Please notice:

I create the custom datatable.

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
        dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dataTable.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");


        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

            document.Open();

            PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataTable.Columns.Count);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName));
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < dataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString()));
                }
            }

            document.Add(pdfTable);

            document.Close();
            writer.Close();

            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();

            string fileName = "DataTable.pdf";
            return File(bytes, "application/pdf", fileName);
        }
```